# Calculating the checksum digit with the Luhn-algorithm

Tags: python, beginner, checksum

I'm doing some exercises in Python and this one is about using the Luhn-algorithm to calculate the checksum digit in Swedish personal identification numbers.

The description is the same as [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57846/calculating-luhn-algorithm-checksum-digit):

> Given a string of 9 digits, `abcdefghi` compute:
>
> ```
> array = [a*2, b, c*2, d, e*2, f, g*2, h, i*2]
> ```
>
> Then you compute the sum of the digits in this array, so for example
>   if `a*2` is 16, then that part counts as `1 + 6`
>
> Then the result is how much more you have to add to make it evenly
>   divisible by 10. For example, if `sum == 54` then the result is 6 as
>   `60 - 54 = 6`.

```
def control_numb(nbr_string):
    cut_string = nbr_string[:9]  ## We need 9 numbers to calculate the 10th
    mult_numb = [2,1]            ## we should alternate multiplying 2 and 1 starting with 2
    i = 0                        ## holds the index of which mult_numt to use. starting with index 0

    sum_of_digits = 0
    for s in cut_string:         ## loop through the string of digits
        for d in str(int(s) * mult_numb[i]):  ## use s as int to do the multiplication. then turn back to str to loop through digit
            sum_of_digits += int(d)
        i = (i+1)%2

    return (10 - sum_of_digits % 10) % 10
```

I'm pretty new to Python and would very much like feedback, if there are any pythonic way to do things please spread the knowledge. Or just tear the code apart completely. Any comments are welcome!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some comments:

- Variable names could be improved a little bit. For example, I think `nbr_string` could be better as `swedish_id`
- Please add a docstring ([PEP257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/))
- `itertools.cycle` is useful to iterate multiple times over the same sequence (in this case, the multiplication factors)
- Use list comprehensions where possible instead of `for` loops

Things that might be different from the question's code:

- I'm assuming the initial string has 9 digits, but if it has already 10, then go with your code to keep only the first 9 numbers, but note that you can use some assertions to be sure the data passed is correct.
- I've calculated partial sums to apply the algorithm as in the explanation, but doing the sums as in the question should be fine.

Please find my solution based on your code below:

```
from itertools import cycle


def control_number(swedish_id):
    """Calculate control number in Swedish personal IDs

    :param swedish_id: A Swedish personal ID
    :type swedish_id: str

    """
    assert swedish_id.isdigit()
    assert len(swedish_id) == 9

    # Multiplication factors for each digit depending on its position
    mult_factors = cycle([2, 1])

    def partial_sum(number, mult_factor):
        """Calculate partial sum ofr a single digit."""
        quotient, remainder = divmod(number * mult_factor, 10)
        return quotient + remainder

    final_sum = sum(
        partial_sum(int(character), mult_factor)
        for character, mult_factor in zip(swedish_id, mult_factors))

    # Calculate control number based on partial sums
    control_number = -final_sum % 10

    return control_number
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: As a quick review to the review : you don't actually need to built the `partial_sums` list as you could just write generator expression and use `sum` : final_sum = sum(partial_sum(number, mult_factor) for number, mult_factor in zip(numbers, mult_factors))`. In the same kind of idea, the `numbers` list is not required (you can call the `int` function as you use it). Also, you could use `divmod` in your `partial_sum` function : `q, r = divmod(n*m, 10); return q+r`.

Comment: @Josay Thanks for your feedback. I've updated the response following your advice and now it looks definitely better. In particular, `divmod` fits really good.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It's very contructiv. :)
A comment on `control_number = 10 - (final_sum % 10)`.
If `final_sum % 10 = 0` then the the function returns 10. It should only return a single digit which in that case would be 0.

Comment: You're right, it fails for `000000000`. I've updated the response with the same code as in the question. I don't like much so many harcoded `10` around, but it don't see any simpler solution.

Comment: Aren't the following values equal : `(10 - (final_sum % 10)) % 10` ; `(- (final_sum % 10)) % 10` ; `(-final_sum % 10) % 10` ; `-final_sum % 10` ?

Comment: @Josay You're absolutely right.
`-final_sum % 10` is both more readable and easy to understand if you know how the modulo operator works. Which every programmer should.

Comment: @AndréSamuelsson That's true for python, but not true for many other programming languages; so if you do use that, add a comment explaining what it does.

Comment: @Josay Awesome! I've updated the code with the simplified version. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

### Interface design

Avoid arbitrarily shortening names of functions — it makes it hard to call them properly.  (You chose "numb"; others might have chosen "num" or "nbr" — which you actually did in the parameter name.)

Since the function accepts a string, it should also return a string.  That would make it convenient to for the caller to concatenate the result after the original non-checksummed version.

### ID number formats

According to Wikipedia, [Swedish Personal Identification numbers](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personnummer_i_Sverige) may have a `+` or `-` sign after the birthdate.  You should ignore it gracefully.

Also, the numbers may sometimes be written with a four-digit year.  However, the checksum digits would still be based on the version with a two-digit year.  I suggest normalizing the input using a regular expression.

### Suggested implementation

```
from itertools import cycle
import re

def control_number(nbr_string):
    def sum_digits((digit, multiplier)):
        sum = int(digit) * multiplier
        return sum if sum < 10 else sum - 9
    # Keep just the relevant digits
    nbr_string = re.sub(r'\d{2}?(\d{6})[+-]?(\d{3})$', r'\1\2', nbr_string)

    total = sum(map(sum_digits, zip(nbr_string, cycle([2, 1]))))
    return str(10 - total % 10)
```